# Compute the daily and hourly salary for staff, truncate to the nearest penny rather than round

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been asked to issue a query to answer a question, the query i have issued is:

SELECT SNAME, TO_CHAR(SAL,'L9,999') AS MONTHLY, TO_CHAR(SAL/22, 'L999.99') AS DAILY, TO_CHAR(SAL/22/8, 'L99.99') AS HOURLY FROM STAFF

But this time i need to truncate to the nearest penny rather than round, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to avoid your question will be closed or get misleading answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple by 100 (so pennies are the units rather than decimals), truncate to the nearest penny and then divide by 100:

```sql
SELECT SNAME,
       TO_CHAR(SAL,'L9,999') AS MONTHLY,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SAL/22*100)/100, 'L999.99') AS DAILY,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SAL/22/8*100)/100, 'L99.99') AS HOURLY
FROM   STAFF
```

or, use the second argument for `TRUNC` to specify the number of deciml places to truncate to:

```sql
SELECT SNAME,
       TO_CHAR(SAL,'L9,999') AS MONTHLY,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SAL/22, 2), 'L999.99') AS DAILY,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SAL/22/8, 2), 'L99.99') AS HOURLY
FROM   STAFF
```

Comment: Using TRUNC to 2 decimal places, **TRUNC(SAL/22, 2)**, yields the same result without having to multiply by 100 and divide by 100.